# Vector reflection relative to a unit vector

Tags: linear-transformations, reflection

I am reading a book by Eric Lengyel, Foundations of Game Development - Mathematics, and I am stumped on a particular statement:

"Suppose the component **v<sub>⊥a</sub>** represents everything that is perpendicular to **a**, we are actually negating a two-dimensional subspace by performing two reflections aligned to vectors that are both orthogonal to **a** and each other." pp. 66

I am not seeing how this differs from reflecting parallel to **a**, which he says that negates only a one-dimensional subspace. I am also not sure what vectors he is referring to when he says "each other" at the end of that statement.

As far as I am concerned, they are both just reflecting once, and negating only one component vector. The only difference I see is the axis that is reflected over.

What does that statement mean? How should I look at this?

Comment: Stand a pencil up on a piece of paper. The pencil is $a$ and the paper is the two dimensional subspace perpendicular to the pencil.  Now draw two perpendicular vectors on the paper at the base of the pencil. That's what they mean by orthogonal to $a$ and each other.

Comment: Sorry cyclo. I wasn't asking what orthogonal means.

Comment: The "each other" means they're all orthogonal to each other. You're probably overthinking it.

Comment: I was misinterpreting the situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author is talking about constructing transform matrices. The first one flips *any* vector vertically through the horizontal plane perpendicular to $\vec a$, this sort of thing:

[image]

The second one flips any vector horizontally (or rather, radially) through $\vec a$ itself (see images in text). Something like this, but all around the vertical axis, in a circle that goes into and out of the the screen:

[image]

> "I am also not sure what vectors he is referring to when he says "each
> other" at the end of that statement."

In the images (in the text), only one $\vec v_{\perp \vec a}$ is shown, but if you consider every possible vector, then there's a whole plane of them. Pick any two orthogonal vectors in that plane.